# Is Haman a child of Amathlaah and a brother to Abraham?

Tags: abraham

https://g.co/kgs/3DRgqQ
It says:

Children- Abraham,Haman
So is he a brother to Abraham and the son to Amathlaah

Comment: Dont use link shorteners

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics.  To understand how we are different to other sites, and what we look for in a well-researched question, please take our Tour: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Questions about biblical topics but without a specific Bible passage are off-topic as hermeneutical methods cannot be applied when no text is referenced.  Is your question related to Genesis 11:26?

Comment: @BethanyHumphreys Perhaps you are referring to "Haman, the son of Hammedatha the Agagite" (Ester 3:1)? This might make Haman a descendent of the Amalekites who were expected to be utterly wiped out by King Saul -- but weren't (1 Samuel 15:8+).

Comment: The name Amathlaah does NOT occur in the Bible so this is not a Biblical question.

Answer (score 1):

The Bible does not say who Abraham’s mother was.  It only says that Abraham’s father was Terah:

> After Terah had lived 70 years, ***he became the father of Abram, Nahor and Haran*** (Genesis 11:26).

Abraham’s wife, Sarai, was the daughter of Abraham’s father, but not the daughter of Abraham’s mother (Genesis 20:12).  However, there is no mention of any Haman.

One Jewish source from the Talmud suggests that Abraham’s mother was Amathlai, the daughter of Karnebo.  As for the genealogy of Abraham, this Wikipedia article gives details on Abraham’s Family Tree: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%27s_family_tree

Haman the Agagite is introduced in Esther 3:5–6 as an enemy of Mordecai and the Jewish people.  He is possibly a descendent of Agag, king of the Amalekites, long-time enemies of the Jewish people.  The Amalekites are not listed in the table of nations in Genesis 10, as they did not originate until after Esau’s time.  You may find these articles helpful:

https://www.gotquestions.org/Haman-the-Agagite.html

https://www.gotquestions.org/Amalekites.html

***Haman was not related to Abraham.***